# Mail.app sending wrong fonts to other email clients/browsers

Tags: font, text

When sending emails from Mail.app, I have Georgia set as the default font in both the body copy and my email signature but they are not being sent correctly. I currently have Georgia 12pt set, and when I send it from Mail.app to ANY other email platform such as Sparrow.app, Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Thunderbird, Outlook... Georgia is not being recognized. As a matter of fact, not even a serif font is being recognized. I've looked all over the internet, posted this issue in Google Forums, tried a Universal Email Plugin, and have had no luck. Does ANYONE know why I'm having this issue and how to fix it?

Please try to find an answer for Georgia. This is a common font and should not have issues. Seriously, Apple... what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

There are three things you're probably running into here:

1. Mail, by default, correctly sends only a plain-text message. Plain text messages carry no style information and will be displayed by the recipient in *their* preferred typeface. Rich-text (HTML) messages are only sent if you've actually used rich-text features.
2. Mail, by default, correctly does not apply a font to rich-text (HTML) messages unless you have explicitly set one while composing it. This allows the recipient to view the message in their preferred typeface, which may well be the only way they can read it. (i.e. If you specify Georgia at 12 pt, it may be completely illegible to someone with impaired vision or a reading disorder.)
3. The "Message font" setting in Preferences controls *your* user interface. It does not affect the message, for reasons of #2, above.